# Why does node finish/close when streaming input via process.stdin?

Tags: node.js, stdin

I am trying to create a node app that you can pipe in JSON data and display it as a question to the user.

I learned how to bind to process.stdin here http://dailyjs.com/2012/03/08/unix-node-pipes/

Here is an example. The following is my UI for asking questions in the terminal.

```
var inquirer = require("inquirer");

function runInquirer(choices) {
  inquirer.prompt([
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      message: "Select toppings",
      name: "toppings",
      choices: choices
    }
  ], function( answers ) {
    console.log( JSON.stringify(answers, null, "  ") );
  });
}
```

If I invoke the handler directly, it works

```
 runInquirer([
   {name:'Cheese'},
   {name:'Tomato'}
 ]);
```

But when I try to pipe the data into it

```
  process.stdin.resume();  
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');  
  process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {        
    runInquirer(JSON.parse(data));
  });
```

It displays the questions and then exits immediately. So it is not waiting for my user input.

Example invoking from the command line (note the pipe | )

```
➜  test git:(master) ✗ cat questions.json | node test.js
? Select toppings (Press <space> to select)
 The usual:
 ❯◯ Peperonni
 ◉ Cheese
```

I have also tried this test with another node user interface library called https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib and got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be misunderstanding a bit about how processes handle `stdin`.  `inquirer.prompt` sets up a prompt by using `stdin` and `stdout` to accept user input and write output to the terminal. `process.stdin.on('data',` sets up a handler to read data as it arrives on `stdin`. When you run

```
cat questions.json | node test.js
```

You are instructing your terminal to stop using the terminal as `stdin` and to instead use the output of the command `cat` as `stdin`.

That means that both of your methods of input are in fact trying to use the same channel. With your current structure, the answer to the question would also have to be coming from your `questions.json` file. It is exiting immediately because the file has run out of content and cannot possibly have any answers for your `inquirer`.

What you probably want is for your `test.js` file to accept a JSON file as the first argument, and read that file instead of reading from `process.stdin`.

Comment: Thank-you for such a detailed response.

Comment: In your answer you say "You are instructing your terminal to stop using the terminal as stdin and to instead use the output of the command cat as stdin." Is there a way to reverse this after I receive what I need from the cat command? I have tried to unbind from the stdin.on('data') event after receiving input but that didn't work.

Comment: There isn't any easy/standard way. This all happens at a pretty low level, so I'd recommend against looking into that farther. The node process itself has no idea that any of this has happened. It is the operating system and bash that start your node process this way by running the command with the `|` like that.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you know if that is a node limitation or am I misunderstanding pipes? How do programs like 'less' handle user input as well as streaming input?

Comment: I actually wasn't sure so I went hunting. There is a node package for everything: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttys Basically it comes down to the fact that you can actually directly read from `/dev/tty` on unix and it will automatically reference the process's terminal, so you can read terminal input from there if `stdin` was redirected. This is also what `less` does. Here's another answer covering this too: http://superuser.com/questions/834502/possible-to-get-a-bash-script-to-accept-input-from-terminal-if-its-stdin-has-bee